# Simple test project with Node.js and RXJS on VS Code

Tags: node.js

I feel very silly not being able to do this, but I am trying to create a simple project to play with some RXJS on Node.js within VS Code.

```
mkdir test
cd test
code .
type nul > app.js
npm init
npm install rxjs
```

app.js contains

```
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';

rxjs.of(1, 2, 3);

var msg = 'Hello World';
console.log(msg);
```

debugging the application gave the runtime error: `(node:9988) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`

So I added:

```
"type": "module"
```

to package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4"
  }
}
```

And now I am getting `TypeError: rxjs.of is not a function`

Why is it so complicated to do something so simple?
What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';
```

use

```
const rxjs = require('rxjs');
```

Currently node doesn't support esmodules